# Creating Excel macros from python

Tags: python, excel, vba, win32com

I would like to create a Excel VBA macro from python.
I already managed to add a module sheet via win32com, but I dont know how to write the code into the module. Here is the code I am using:

```
import win32com.client
xl = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible=True
out_file = "workbook.xlsm"
xl.Workbooks.Open(out_file)
Book=xl.Application.Workbooks(1)
newModule=Book.Modules.Add()
```

Now: How do I write a string containing the macro into the new module sheet?

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) and [Without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Comment: Is it really necessary to create new code? It's almost always much easier to have the code stored in an Excel workbook and use that as a template.